# How much do you control a 'Find Steed' mount when you are unmounted?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, mounted-combat

There have been [multiple questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/can-a-mount-attack-while-it-is-being-ridden) asked about the specifics of mounted combat, especially as a paladin. [Some of them have been conflicting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79026/mounted-combat-specifics-for-this-turn) and are mostly based on the rules we have in PHB p198 and on Jeremy Crawford's tweets:

- [Not Independent.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/635938490274811905?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

  > The mount summoned by the find steed spell serves the summoner. It isn't an independent creature.
- [Still has normal mounted combat options](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/636293240749056000?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

  > While ridden, the steed follows the normal mounted combat rules (PH, 198). Unridden, it has normal action options.

From what I gather from this, a mount summoned from the '[Find Steed](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Steed#content)' spell is intelligent and loyal enough to obey your orders without question while you are mounted on it, but is not considered an 'Intelligent creature', which could use any type of action while you are mounted, but may go against your orders. This is called an 'independent creature' in the PHB. While mounted, the non-independent creature has only the Dash, Disengage and Dodge actions, along with moving.

I have an issue with the accepted answer for this [similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99903/how-does-a-mount-from-find-steed-act-when-unmounted), which says the following:

> 3. The mount is "unusually intelligent": without direction it will use its movement etc. in an "unusually intelligent" way. With direction it will probably do what you telepathically say but it is an independent creature and, at the DM's behest, may do something different subject to its "unusual loyalty".
> 4. When you mount your mount you *choose* if you will control it or if, as it is "unusually intelligent", you will allow it to act independently as per the rules for [mounted combat](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Steed#content). It all cases that I can think of, allowing it to be independent is the superior option.

To me this goes against Jeremy Crawford's tweets : the mount is not an independent creature and cannot be used as such.

Therefore, how exactly would an unmounted paladin direct, say, a summoned warhorse, during combat? Would he fully control the creature, through telepathy, allowing for attacks and trampling charges? How much does the DM has a say in whether or not the creature chooses to obey or not?