# Can a mount use the Help action in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, helping

[This question by V2Blast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121359/47117) piqued my interest into the subject of what mounts can and cannot do.

If a paladin uses the [*find steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed) spell to find a mount that could possibly attack and such, could he get off his mount and have it use the [Help action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Help) to distract an enemy in order to gain advantage on the next attack against that enemy?

Comment: Semi-related: ["How does a mount from Find Steed act when unmounted?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99903/how-does-a-mount-from-find-steed-act-when-unmounted), ["Is a pegasus summoned by Find Greater Steed controlled or independent when mounted?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116649/is-a-pegasus-summoned-by-find-greater-steed-controlled-or-independent-when-mount), ["Mounted Combat - Specifics for this turn"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79026/mounted-combat-specifics-for-this-turn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Technically yes.

Following [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99903/how-does-a-mount-from-find-steed-act-when-unmounted#116647) pointed out by V2Blast:

While mounted, you can choose whether to control it or let it be independent. If you choose to control it, it is limited by the normal rules to the Dash, Dodge and Disengage actions, but if you use it as an uncontrolled mount, it can do whatever.

While dismounted, the steed takes part in combat as a normal creatures would and:

> When a monster takes its action, it can choose from the options in the Actions section of its stat block or use one of the actions available to all creatures, such as the Dash or Hide action.

And so it is free to use the *Help* action. Moreover, you are able to fully command it.

Comment: The spell explicitly mentions you can telepathically communicate with the steed out to a distance of 1 mile, which suggests the steed will at least be responsive and somewhat active while you're not mounted.

Comment: I think it mentions somewhere in the spell that you and your mount fight as a *seamless unit*. I have no doubt that the steed would use it if it could, I just wasn't sure if it could in the first place.

Comment: The rule you quote at the beginning only holds for *controlled* mounts. The spell makes it a point to raise the steed's Int to 6, so it might be able to act independently.

Comment: @Szega: See [Rubiksmoose's answer to a question on whether a mount from *find steed* is controlled or uncontrolled](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116647/33569), and specifically the Crawford tweets regarding how it behaves when unmounted: ["Unridden, \[the steed from Find Steed\] has normal action options."](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/636293240749056000) and ["Find steed: you can command your steed however you like while you're not mounted."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/755210566642262016) It obeys the summoner's commands regardless of whether it's ridden.

Comment: @V2Blast That answer reinforces my position. It says you can choose to let it act independently. That the steed follows your commands does not mean that it automatically counts as "controlled".

Comment: @Szega: I know it supports your point, that's why I linked it :P (I also changed it halfway through, but looking back at J.E's answer now, the linked answer does clarify that you don't need to dismount it to let it act independently and that's what I'd initially meant to point out.)

Comment: Time to edit the answer then!